# Start $index at 1 in Ng Repeat

Tags: angularjs, paypal

Is there a way to use 1 instead of 0 for $index in ng-repeat as the initial item? Im not trying to filter out the first item in the array. It is for paypal they want the first to be item_num_1... using 0 doesnt work
as in

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items">
<input type ="hidden" name ="item_num_{{$index}}" value ="item_num_{{item.id}}">
//the rest like this
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can try this. I am not sure if it works though. Good luck

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in items track by $index">
<input type ="hidden" name ="item_num_{{$index + 1}}" value ="item_num_{{item.id}}">
//the rest like this
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not to do just

```
{{$index+1}}
```